# 404 error in ng-src before get response and full loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use ng-src inside ng-repeat

for example i'm in this page :
http://localhost/nic-video/1397/08/this-is-my-samle-post

my ng-repeat loop when page loading is empty and by click a button and send request will full

```html
 <!-- Ajax Request Result Loop -->
<article ng-if="related_video.length > 0" ng-cloak ng-repeat="video in related_video track by $index" id="video-{{ video.id }}">
  <div class="thumb">
      <a ng-href="{{video.permalink}}" title="{{video.title}}">
          <img ng-cloak ng-if="video.thumbnail != null" ng-src="video.thumbnail" class="animate-opacity" />
      </a>
  </div>
</article>
```

but, when load page and don't send any request my ng-src has this error 404 :

GET http://localhost/nic-video/1397/08/this-is-my-samle-postvideo.thumbnail 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
ng-src="video && video.thumbnail ? video.thumbnail"
```

or check with an ng-if

```
<img ng-if="video && video.thumbnail" ng-cloak ng-if="video.thumbnail != null" ng-src="video.thumbnail" class="animate-opacity" />
```

Comment: it's ok .
but when use <picture> tag and insert img tag inside it , this error back again.
i use <picture> tag with many source tag for change images in any size

Comment: then put the same condition on the picture tag - <picture ng-if="video && video.thumbnail"></picture>